# (BATCH) Directory names

Tags: batch-file

I've been wondering about the "%Windir%" and such and i am trying to ask what other directory names are there (other than the %windir%), i've been trying to find out what they are, but it showed no results whatsoever.

I'm sorry for asking this stupid question in the first place... I was doing a ton of research and some of them didnt work out properly and i was hoping for easier ways to get what I wanted. Sorry guys =(

Comment: This command will list all environment variables: `set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full list, access them by typing `set` at command prompt. Be sure to %wrap% in %'s

```
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\KNUCKLE-DRAGGER\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=BOX
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\KNUCKLE-DRAGGER
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\KNUCKLE-DRAGGER\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\BOX
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 11, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=0f0b
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TEMP=C:\Users\KNUCK-~1\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\KNUCK-~1\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=BOX
USERNAME=KNUCKLE-DRAGGER
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\KNUCKLE-DRAGGER
windir=C:\Windows
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET
```

It'll display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.

[Read more........](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)